# How to get all table names and all column and row names for each table?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlclient

I need to query a SQL database using the C# `System.Data.SqlClient` dll. I know I can typically query the database using SQL query statement like `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`. However, I don't know any of the table, column, or row names so I do not know how to properly get the information I need.

I tried the following code already after another answer I saw on SO:

```
public void PrintNames() // print table, column, and row names
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    using (connection)
    {
        connection.Open();

        DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
        Debug.Log(table.Columns.Count);
        Debug.Log(table.Rows.Count);

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
               Debug.Log(col.ToString() + ", " + row.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This just results in printing the following: `TABLE_CATALOG, System.Data.DataRow` over and over again.

Also if you're wondering why the `Debug.Log` stuff, it's because I'm using Unity3D, but this problem has nothing to do with Unity so I didn't bother adding a tag for it.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: row.ToString() would write as DataRow; you need to try to index it to get value of a cell, like row[col.ToString()] or getting indexer and loping thrugh index count

Comment: @techspider makes sense but why does `col.ToString()` print something then?

Comment: hmm.... put a breakpoint and go over col.ToString() to see what property it is trying to write; it appears that you wrote code without understanding what it does!!

Comment: @techspider You are absolutely correct! Haha I have never done DB stuff before and this seemed like a good place to start. As for printing col.ToString() it appears this is printing a property which DataRow does not have, which is why it prints the data type instead.

Comment: what do you need at all? list of all tables and all column names in each table?

Comment: @techspider Yes and how to get data from a specific row in that column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110862/discussion-between-techspider-and-bpgeck).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you means be row names, but you can get information about database metadata using [Information Schema Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` returns one row for each table in the current database for which the current user has permissions.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` returns one row for each column that can be accessed by the current user in the current database.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME                        //SELECT ONLY THE NAME OF THE TABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES           //READ FROM TABLES VIEW
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG='database name'      //KEEP ONLY VALUES OF YOUR DATABASE
```

And to get all columns of a table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME                      //SELECT ONLY THE NAME OF THE COLUMN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS         //READ FROM COLUMNS VIEW
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG='database name'     //KEEP ONLY VALUES OF YOUR DATABASE
  AND TABLE_NAME='table name'           //AND A SPECIFIC TABLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to SQL and databases in general. Would you mine walking me through your answer so I know what each line does?

Comment: @bpgeck: ok, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: yes, is the name of the database you want to know about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system views in SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName, c.Name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.tables t
INNER join sys.columns c
  ON t.object_id = c.object_id
ORDER BY t.name, c.column_id
```

You can add conditions into the `WHERE` clause if you want to filter down the results even more.